# xamarin forms: swipe to delete

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

How can I add Swipe to delete in my note list app.I am using xamarin forms. I have searched in xamarin forms samples but could not find it. I also tried the list view performance options with menuItem etc but I dont know how to adjust that in my code. Can anyone help me with this please?
My code is as follows:

```
public partial class MyPage
{
    List<Note> notes;
    string NotesFile {
        get {
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            return System.IO.Path.Combine (documents, "notes.json");
        }
    }
    public MyPage()
    {
        BuildContent();
        LoadNotes ();
        ReloadListContents ();

        AddNoteButton.Clicked += (sender, args) => {
            var note = new Note("typ...");
            notes.Add(note);
            EditNote(note);
        };

        NoteListView.ItemTapped += (sender, row) =>
        {
            NoteListView.SelectedItem = null;
            Note note = (Note)row.Item;
            EditNote(note);
        };

        buttonDelete.Clicked += (sender, args) =>{
            notes.RemoveAt(0);
            DisplayAlert("Delete", "Row deleted", "OK");
        };
    }
```

}
MyPage.cs

```
{
    public ListView NoteListView = new ListView ();
    public Button AddNoteButton;
    public Button buttonDelete;
    private void BuildContent() 
    {
        AddNoteButton = new Button
        {
            Text = "Add New Note",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };
        buttonDelete = new Button
        {
            Text = "Delete Note ",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    Text = "Note Taker",
                    TextColor = Color.White
                },
                NoteListView,
                AddNoteButton,
                buttonDelete
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: These are just parts of code.

Comment: See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Context_Actions

Comment: Thank you. But i tried this one. How can i adjust this in my code. I am not using TextCell so contextActions will not work. Any other idea to arrange this?

Comment: @preet, Context actions are part of View Cell classes, if you want to have that ability you will need to use a view cell, otherwise adding a swipe gesture recognizer might work. Something like this perhaps http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Im responding to this question in CS code rather than XAML (My Preferred) if anyone would like the Xaml response please drop a comment below and I'll write the XAML alongside the CS.

So to complete what you have asked in Xamarin.Forms on ListView elements you must first create the ViewCell that you would like to display the data in each cell in the ListView and give it context actions. Here is an example:

```
   public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
        {
            public CustomViewCell()
            {
                //instantiate each element we want to use.
                var image = new CircleCachedImage
                {
                    Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 0, 10),
                    WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth * 0.15,
                    HeightRequest = App.ScreenWidth * 0.15,
                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                    BorderColor = Color.FromHex(App.PrimaryColor),
                    BorderThickness = 2,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                };
                var nameLabel = new Label
                {
                    Margin = new Thickness(20, 15, 0, 0),
                    FontFamily = "Lato",
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    FontSize = 17
                };
                var locationLabel = new Label
                {
                    Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 5),
                    FontFamily = "Lato",
                    FontSize = 13
                };
                //Create layout
                var verticaLayout = new StackLayout();
                var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.White };

                //set bindings
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
                locationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Location"));
                image.SetBinding(CircleCachedImage.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));

                //Set properties for desired design
                horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
                horizontalLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
                image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;


                //add views to the view hierarchy
                horizontalLayout.Children.Add(image);
                verticaLayout.Children.Add(nameLabel);
                verticaLayout.Children.Add(locationLabel);
                horizontalLayout.Children.Add(verticaLayout);

                //HERE IS THE MOST IMPORTANT PART
                var deleteAction = new MenuItem { Text = "Delete", IsDestructive = true }; // red background


                deleteAction.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
                    //Here do your deleting / calling to WebAPIs
                    //Now remove the item from the list. You can do this by sending an event using messaging center looks like: 
                    //MessagingCenter.Send<TSender,string>(TSender sender, string message, string indexOfItemInListview)
                };
                // add to the ViewCell's ContextActions property
                ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);

                // add to parent view
                View = horizontalLayout;
            }
        }
```

Now you must do the following to your ListView:

```
listView = new ListView();
lstView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomViewCell));
```

In the same Content Page that you have the ListView you must also subscirbe to the [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) listening to the same parameters as set in the custom view cell as above. Please read the link provided if you have not used the MessagingCenter before. Inside of this method you must then remove the item from the listview with the index sent to this method.

If anyone needs any further explanations drop a comment below and Ill edit this post.